# React Native. Android. Push Notifications Permission

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification

does anyone know how to check user permissions for push notifications in react native?

I checked all available methods in react native docs and checked npm packages, like react-native-permissions.

Comment: What permissions do you think that "push notifications" need?

Answer (score 0):

Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY

or

You can receive Push Notifications if you have Internet permission, Connected Internet and properly.

I hope it helps!